# Android PHP MySQL Update - script works (db updated), but it throws error back to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Took the plunge into Android development (mostly for fun).  I do have programming experience but not in Java.

Working on an activity where the user is pre-assigned a password they have to change when they first login.  I basically duplicated the Login PHP and tweaked it to do an update (instead of checking for a valid username/pw).  The php returns an error BUT, the password is actually updated in the database.  Which does me no good since Android thinks there was an error.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $con=mysqli_connect(“server”,”user”,”pw”,”db”);

        $sql ="UPDATE coaches SET coach_pw = '$password' WHERE (((coach_id)='$username'))";

        $check = mysqli_query(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

        if(isset($check)){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
   }else{
        echo "error try again";
 }
?>
```

The error I get back from PHP (from AS debug): html markup & "PHP Error Message" & html markup.

The last thing I changed that I thought was the problem was the mysqli_ function I was using (_fetch_array instead of _query).  But that didn't fix the issue.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you writing twice mysqli_query(mysqli_query(... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as Bang said in his comment, the double use of the mysqli_query function explains why the script returns an error.

Your query is correctly executed by the inner mysqli_query(), wich returns TRUE. This return value is then executed by the outer mysqli_query() wich, of course, returns an error.

That is why the query is successfully executed but an error is sent.